# Selenium proxy on aws kubernetes instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, proxy

i've installed selenium grid via helm charts, and i cannot tests with selenium proxy configured against it.
Locally (with a local selenium instance) it works fine, the httpProxy is being started and the test runs fine.

Selenium Grid 4.0.0
Firefox v.89
OS Arch: amd64
OS Name: Linux

Stacktrace:
`org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: [Exception... "Component is not available"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: about:neterror?e=proxyConnectFailure&u=http%3A//<hidden url>&c=UTF-8&d=Firefox%20is%20configured%20to%20use%20a%20proxy%20server%20that%20is%20refusing%20connections. :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 2"  data: no] Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host: 'LT132925', ip: '192.168.1.125', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.14' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 89.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20210614221319, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.29.1, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 6964, moz:profile: /tmp/rust_mozprofilen1X715, moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: LINUX, platformName: LINUX, platformVersion: 5.10.186-179.751.amzn2.x86_64, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=localhos..., se:vnc: ws://172.31.8.43:5555/sessi..., se:vncEnabled: true, se:vncLocalAddress: ws://localhost:7900/websockify, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: accept} Session ID: 99349203-142e-4182-bb34-aec98efdac8c at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552) at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:489)`

I was expecting the test to run smoothly with the selenium proxy, as it does so locally.